# Creating an XMPP GTalk chat app with jQuery/Phono

Tags: jquery, xmpp, google-talk, phono

So I've been working with [phono.js](http://www.phono.com/) which is an amazing new jQuery library. It supports XMPP client chats, so I'm looking for a way to setup live chats with GTalk accounts. The documentation isn't really supported very well...

If anybody has a better solution for creating a GTalk app in-browser I'd love to hear. but jQuery seems like the best way and Phono even supports the XMPP protocol! So my thought was try here first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like phono.js is tied to their service.  As such, create a user there, add that user to your GTalk roster, and send a message to the GTalk user's Jabber ID (same as their GMail address).  The two servers will federate together behind the scenes.

```
$.phono({
  onReady: function() {
     this.messaging.send("example@gmail.com","Hello");
  }
})
```